# How do I remove a vertical line from a button with SVG background?

Tags: html, css, svg

We have a button with a background in SVG, and there is a vertical line on the right side with Chrome - but only in the desktop (Chrome version 90.0.4430.93) and not with Firefox. I'm trying to remove the vertical line. How do I remove the vertical line?

The website is https://en.speedymatch.com/, screenshot: [image: screenshot]

The HTML is:

```html
<div class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="submit"
    name="submit"
    value="Create an account"
    
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-arrow-right"
        id="submit-id-submit"
    
    
    /> </div> </div>
```

CSS is:

```css
.btn-primary.btn-arrow-right,
.btn-primary.btn-arrow-right:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):not(:focus):active,
.btn-primary.btn-arrow-right:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):not(:focus).active {
  background-color: #ff1c32;
  -webkit-mask: url("/static/speedy-match/images/btn-arrow-right.svg") no-repeat;
  border: transparent;
  padding-right: 3em; }
```

And the SVG file does not contain a vertical line.

Comment: try background-clip:padding-box and add a small transparent border on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but the vertical line disappears if I add the following CSS:

```css
background-clip: padding-box;
border-right: 1px solid transparent;
```

Comment: use transparent instead of white and then add background-clip:padding-box

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer but... why do you use a `background-image` when that shape can be easily done with just pure `css`?. like this:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:40px;
  padding-left:10px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a shape</div>
```

Comment: You are right, but we had problems with CSS and we changed to SVG recently.